# SQL get first non value based on status

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not sure if the title is correct but here's my question. I have a table like this:

```
+----+--------+--------------+---------+------------+
| id |  city  |   province   | status  |    date    |
+----+--------+--------------+---------+------------+
|  1 | cainta | rizal        | failed  | 01/01/2020 |
|  1 | null   | null         | success | 02/01/2020 |
|  1 | cainta | rizal        | failed  | 03/01/2020 |
|  2 | pasig  | metro manila | failed  | 04/01/2020 |
|  2 | pasig  | metro manila | failed  | 05/01/2020 |
|  2 | null   | null         | success | 06/01/2020 |
|  3 | obando | bulacan      | failed  | 07/01/2020 |
|  3 | null   | null         | failed  | 08/01/2020 |
|  3 | obando | bulacan      | success | 09/01/2020 |
+----+--------+--------------+---------+------------+
```

Now I need to get all transactions with status='success'. If I do that the output will be like this:

```
|   id | city   | province   | status   | date       |
|------|--------|------------|----------|------------|
|    1 | nan    | nan        | success  | 02/01/2020 |
|    2 | nan    | nan        | success  | 06/01/2020 |
|    3 | obando | bulacan    | success  | 09/01/2020 |
```

What I need is this:

```
|   id | city   | province     | status   | date       |
|------|--------|--------------|----------|------------|
|    1 | cainta | rizal        | success  | 02/01/2020 |
|    2 | pasig  | metro manila | success  | 06/01/2020 |
|    3 | obando | bulacan      | success  | 09/01/2020 |
```

Hopefully someone can shed some light on how to tackle this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following using `lag()`

```
with cte as
(
  select
      *,
      lag(city) over (order by id) as ncity,
      lag(province) over (order by id) as nprovince
  from myTable
)

select
    id,
    coalesce(city, ncity) as city,
    coalesce(province, nprovince) as province,
    status,
    date
from cte
where status = 'success';
```

output:

```
| id  | city   | province     | status  | date       |
| --- | ------ | ------------ | ------- | ---------- |
| 1   | cainta | rizal        | success | 02/01/2020 |
| 2   | pasig  | metro manila | success | 06/01/2020 |
| 3   | obando | bulacan      | success | 09/01/2020 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytical functions here.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT T.ID, T.CITY, T.PROVINCE,
        MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'success' THEN DATE END) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) AS DATE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) AS RN,
        SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS CNT
  FROM YOUR_TABLE T)
 WHERE RN = 1 AND CNT > 0
```

As you have changed the sample data, You can use the `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(CITY) AS CITY, MAX(PROVINCE) AS PROVINCE, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'success' THEN DATE END) AS DATE
  FROM YOUR_TABLE 
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'success' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Comment: I have added a filter on dates in Having clause, but the time to query takes too long, around 10 rows per second. Can you suggest ways to speed up the query execution? thanks!

Comment: It will return only one record per ID having max success date.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a window function can help:

```
SELECT id, city, province, status, date
FROM (SELECT id,
             max(city) OVER w AS city,
             max(province) OVER w AS province,
             status,
             date
      FROM atable
      WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id)) AS q
WHERE status = 'success';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just one row per id, you can use aggregation:

```
select id, max(city) as city, max(province) as province,
       max(date) filter (where status = 'success') as date
from t
group by id
having count(*) filter (where status = 'success') > 0;
```

Note that if you can have multiple success dates per id, you can put the on the same row using `array_agg()`:

```
       array_agg(date) filter (where status = 'success') as dates
```